# What happens to your stomach on extended IV fluid treatment?

Tags: stomach

When someone has to go on extended IV, like when they got into an accident, and cannot eat anything for an extended period, what happens to their stomach and gut? Does it fully recover? How does the stomach and gut deal with lack of food and fluid?